# Node JS + Express + Mongoose not filling array from findById

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need to edit a Game object by adding a User object to it. This is done by the mongoose query findById. This query works. But however, when I want to add the modified game to the resulting array, something goes wrong. The 'console.log(game);' returns the right output, but the 'console.log(result);' is always empty. What is going wrong? Is it something with inner functions?

```
            var result = [];
            games.forEach(function(game){
                User.findById(game.user1_id, function(err, user){
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err);
                    game.user1 = user;
                    result.push(game);
                    console.log(game);
                });

            });
            console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run into a class callback problem. When you call `forEach` on games the code will actually continue outside the callback and the result will therefore be the value you first assigned to it, which is `[]`. This is due to the code being evaluated asynchronous.

Solve this by moving your code into a function with a callback that is called when the loop is done, like this:

```
var utils = require('restberry-utils');

var getResult = function(next) {
    var result = [];
    utils.forEachAndDone(games, function(game, iter) {
        User.findById(game.user1_id, function(err, user) {
            if (err)  console.log(err);
            game.user1 = user;
            result.push(game);
            iter();
        });
    }, function() {
        next(result);
    });
};

getResult(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Notice I've imported the `restberry-utils` package and used the `forEachAndDone` method. This method will loop through the objects but won't continue unless you call the `iter` method. When it has looped through all the objects, the last callback is called which is where I'm returning the result.

Hope this makes sense.